# Wordpress Single post content sidebar

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

In the single post page if I want to place post's title and image on top (100% width) and below them the content on left with sidebar on right is it ok to put the sidebar in the article ?

```
   <main class="main" role="main">
       <article id="post-65035" class="post type-post">
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h1 class="entry-title"></h1>              
            </header>

            <div class="entry-image">
            </div>

            <div class="entry-content">
            </div>

            <aside class="sidebar">
            </aside>
       </article>
   </main>
```

Comment: should be fine, can't see why that should bug anything

Comment: you might have to rewrite some CSS though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes: **default** looks like this , inside an `div`

```
 <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
 </div>
```

So for yours if you do it like this you wil have to customize the `css`.

```
<aside class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
   <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</aside>
```